# Color format of texture created by CVOpenGLTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage (for OSX/MAC, NOT ES)

Tags: macos, opengl, opengl-es, core-video

I've been experimenting with OpenGL on OSX with a ES implementation as reference code. The goal is to render an image buffer (CVImageBuffer) which is in the yuv format.

I need to know how to specify the color format (or is it fixed to a particular type?) of the texture that gets created using `CVOpenGLTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()` API. I'm trying to figure this out so that I can appropriately access/process the colors in the fragment shader (RGB vs YUV).

Also, I can see that there is an "internalFormat" option that can be used to control this in the OpenGL-ES version of the API.

Thanks!

Comment: "*pixel-buffer format*" What do you mean by this?

Comment: Nicol, I ment color-format (corrected now).

Comment: MSQRD team here, trying to understand same thing right now. What we found is only Metal API (OS X 10.11+) which helps to achieve this on OS X. (public func CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(allocator: CFAllocator?, _ textureCache: CVMetalTextureCache, _ sourceImage: CVImageBuffer, _ textureAttributes: CFDictionary?, _ pixelFormat: MTLPixelFormat, _ width: Int, _ height: Int, _ planeIndex: Int, _ textureOut: UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CVMetalTexture>?>) -> CVReturn)

Comment: Thanks for the reply MSQRD Team, Do you know if I can just mix this one metal call to create texture with my other CoreVideo-OpenGL Calls? ....... Earlier, I had proceeded to work around the problem by assuming the color format to be ARGB everywhere and got my app working. However, I was told that yuv format will help in the application' perfomance since it occupies less memory foot print. So, Now I have come back to this problem.